# Comparing jQuery returned string with another string

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to compare a jQuery returned string (accessed by `msg.d`) and another string. This is currently what I have done, but it seems like it's not working and saying it's not equal every time:

```
setTimeout(ReloadChatMsgs, 1000);
function ReloadChatMsgs() {
    var msgs = document.getElementById("msgs_list");
    $.when($.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: 'Login.aspx/ReloadChatMsgs',
        data: '{}',
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (msg) {
            if (msgs.innerHTML != msg.d.toString())
                msgs.innerHTML = msg.d;
        },
        failure: function (e) {

        }
    })).then(function () { setTimeout(ReloadChatMsgs, 1000); });
}
```

Comment: some error in console? `msgs.innerHTML` and `msg.d` are defined? are you sure that the output of `msg.d.toString()` are what you expected?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to compare two strings irrespective of case

1. Trim both the strings
2. Convert both to lowercase

Code:

```
if ($.trim(msgs.innerHTML.toLowerCase()) != $.trim(msg.d.toString().toLowerCase()))
    msgs.innerHTML = msg.d
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

I just checked both values of `msg.d` and `msgs.innerHTML` and they are a bit different because `msgs.innerHTML` is already parsed to HTML codes (space for example). I resolved it by saving the last msg.d in a different var and used this to compare.

```
var last_msgs_set = "";
setTimeout(ReloadChatMsgs, 1000);
function ReloadChatMsgs() {
    var msgs = document.getElementById("msgs_list");
    $.when($.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: 'Login.aspx/ReloadChatMsgs',
        data: '{}',
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (msg) {
            if (last_msgs_set != msg.d) {
                msgs.innerHTML = msg.d;
                last_msgs_set = msg.d;
            }
        },
        failure: function (e) {

        }
    })).then(function () { setTimeout(ReloadChatMsgs, 1000); });
}
```